# UIBarButton appearance´s issue

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I need to change the cancel´s Button of My **UISearcBar**.

I am using the **appearanceWhenContainedIn** method of iOS 5, but it shows me a strange behavior, **the button gets stretched horizontally** ..

[image]

I am implemented this code:

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Any Idea why this happen?

Comment: This might help you.
[uibarbuttonitem-via-appearance][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301555/setbackgroundimage-for-uibarbuttonitem-via-appearance-not-working-for-other-uico

Comment: Thanks... This just solve my problem!!!